# Entering A price

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatatypes

What would be the best way to set my SQL field for a value such as **$34,000**.

My SQL is: `price DECIMAL(4,2)` and it seems I can only output 34.00.  How could I also make it show with a , not a . (could possibly be to due my cms stripping data)

Comment: Alternately, you could use an integer and store your prices as the total number of cents (i.e. '3400000' for '$34000').

Comment: You should specify whether your value '$34,000' is 34 (with decimal comma), or 34000 (with thousands separator). Output of decimal separator should be controlled at view stage by setting appropriate locale for UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $34,000 you need DECIMAL(7,2), five digits before the decimal point, two after.

And think about if you really need to be so restrictive. Two decimals after the point makes sense, but you want to err on the safe side with the total number, otherwise you cannot store say, $1,000,000, in your database.

Comment: Indeed. I typically implement no less than DECIMAL(10,2), there's really no need to purposefully restrict your application. The change to overhead is negligible.